# How correctly to import visao/ckeditor5-video plugin?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I use ckeditor 38 in Laravel 8 / jquery 3.6.0  app
and I added https://github.com/Technologie-Visao/ckeditor5-video plugin(28.0.1)

But I failed to add it into my app.js file, as when I added import Video  :

```
import Video from "@visao/ckeditor5-video/src/video.js";

const ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#content_editor'), {
        plugins: [Video],
        video: {           // video properties
            upload: {
                types: ['mp4'],
                allowMultipleFiles: false,
            },
        },
        extraPlugins: [ NewUploadAdapterPlugin ]  // I also have images plugin inserted
    })
```

But in browser's console I got error :

```
app.js?id=a3275a152c6ddc2953f0f639d1375f5f:16 Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules
    at app.js?id=a3275a152c6ddc2953f0f639d1375f5f:16:390578
    at app.js?id=a3275a152c6ddc2953f0f639d1375f5f:16:1127587
    at app.js?id=a3275a152c6ddc2953f0f639d1375f5f:16:1127603
    at app.js?id=a3275a152c6ddc2953f0f639d1375f5f:16:36
    at ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js
```

I cannot comment like with  const ClassicEditor = ...

As I got :

```
ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined
```

error ...

Which is valid code to import ?

**UPDATED BLOCK :**

At this
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/plugins/installing-plugins.html#requirements
page I read :

> When installing CKEditor 5 Framework packages, you need to make sure
> their versions match the version of the base editor package. For
> example: if you would like to install the
> @ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment package and your other packages are
> outdated, e.g. at version 38.0.0, you should consider updating your
> editor and all other packages to the latest 39.0.0 version. You might
> also install the alignment package at version 38.0.0 (which is not
> advised, actually). Otherwise, if package versions are different, this
> will result in an ckeditor-duplicated-modules error.
>
> The simplest way to avoid such situations is to always use the latest
> 39.0.0 versions of the official packages. If you already stumbled upon this error, you can use npm-check-updates, which is a handy tool for
> keeping your packages up to date.

In package.json I have :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@visao/ckeditor5-video": "^28.0.1",

"dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^38.0.1",
```

Looks like as https://github.com/Technologie-Visao/ckeditor5-video has 2 years of last - so
update there is no way to install  it  under ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic 38.0.1 ?

So I  changed :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^28.0.0",
```

Next Totally removed package-lock.json and node_modules and run

```
npm install
```

and

```
npm run watch-poll
```

But anyway I got errors :

```
app.js?id=d45135773663b89e3badb99a4913df66:14 Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js?id=d45135773663b89e3badb99a4913df66:14:8607)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js?id=d45135773663b89e3badb99a4913df66:14:8681)
    at i (app.js?id=d45135773663b89e3badb99a4913df66:14:3715)
    at Module.<anonymous> (app.js?id=d45135773663b89e3badb99a4913df66:14:115934)
    at i (app.js?id=d45135773663b89e3badb99a4913df66:14:3715)
    at app.js?id=d45135773663b89e3badb99a4913df66:14:4514
    at app.js?id=d45135773663b89e3badb99a4913df66:14:4525
    at app.js?id=d45135773663b89e3badb99a4913df66:14:3574
    at ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js (app.js?id=d45135773663b89e3badb99a4913df66:14:3580)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=d45135773663b89e3badb99a4913df66:125260:42)
```

I opened composer.lock and check :

```
 "": {
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^28.0.0",
        ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@visao/ckeditor5-video": "^28.0.0",
        ...
    }


...

"node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": {
    "version": "28.0.0",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/-/ckeditor5-build-classic-28.0.0.tgz",
    "integrity": "sha512-VgOGAMC9/47HZTgA4vnzhYfNCYRYzukXuS873B0gQ9cenP13CnYzwa1y9H/Przo4r5sYUPsNsLCG1i5eM58JWg==",
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table": "^28.0.0",
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing": "^28.0.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=12.0.0",
        "npm": ">=5.7.1"
    }
},

...

"node_modules/@visao/ckeditor5-video": {
    "version": "28.0.1",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@visao/ckeditor5-video/-/ckeditor5-video-28.0.1.tgz",
    "integrity": "sha512-1w2HyfirebuIq8Wqt9x4Hy2wMSaJC75YIlQCq5ZIJc0Z3WUCPxr9n+M9czs/oLmasa+bOWCzcZjzpZfPRyd6Vg==",
    "dev": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui": "^28.0.0",
        "ckeditor5": "^28.0.0"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=12.0.0",
        "npm": ">=5.7.1"
    }
},
```

I expected that downgrading of version ckeditor5-build-classic till 28.0 will fix this error, but I failed...

**UPDATED BLOCK # 2:**
I found package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video, which is Last publish
9 months ago, but again compiling project with packages :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^35.0.0",
    "@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video": "^35.2.2",
```

and with code :

```
import Video from "@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video/src/video"
...
const ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic')

ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#content_editor'), {
        plugins: [Video],
        vide: {
            upload: {
                types: ['mp4'],
                allowMultipleFiles: false,
            },
        },
        extraPlugins: [ NewUploadAdapterPlugin ]
    })
```

I got the same erro :

```
app.js?id=d116dabf1545386811d197adc4a998f3:16 Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules
    at app.js?id=d116dabf1545386811d197adc4a998f3:16:311177
    at app.js?id=d116dabf1545386811d197adc4a998f3:16:1002139
    at app.js?id=d116dabf1545386811d197adc4a998f3:16:1002155
    at app.js?id=d116dabf1545386811d197adc4a998f3:16:36
    at ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js (app.js?id=d116dabf1545386811d197adc4a998f3:16:42)
```

Not sure, but seems zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video is latest version of Technologie-Visao/ckeditor5-video I used firstly:

**Updated Block 3:**
I try to follow instructions.
I also had to install into the project:

```
npm i @ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark
```

But compiling the project I but got many errors :

```
$ npm run build

> my-ckeditor-build@1.0.0 build
> webpack --mode production

assets by status 749 KiB [cached] 1 asset
orphan modules 6.09 MiB [orphan] 1424 modules
runtime modules 919 bytes 5 modules
cacheable modules 5.61 MiB
  modules with errors 2.29 KiB [errors]
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ 1.18 KiB 31 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video/ 1.1 KiB 29 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/color-convert/*.js 20.5 KiB
    ./node_modules/color-convert/index.js 1.67 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/color-convert/conversions.js 16.6 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/color-convert/route.js 2.2 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./ckeditor.js + 916 modules 5.58 MiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js 6.67 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/color-name/index.js 4.51 KiB [built] [code generated]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/theme/clipboard.css (./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/theme/clipboard.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'plugins'. These properties are valid:
   object { postcssOptions?, execute?, sourceMap?, implementation? }
    at validate (/ProjectPath/my-ckeditor-build/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:191:11)
    at Object.loader (/ProjectPath/my-ckeditor-build/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:43:29)
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/theme/clipboard.css 2:12-116 9:17-24 13:15-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/src/dragdropexperimental.js 16:0-32
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/src/index.js 12:0-73 12:0-73
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/clipboard.js 8:0-46 8:0-46
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js 9:0-52 35:16-25
 @ ./ckeditor.js 4:0-77 10:4-20

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/theme/classiceditor.css (./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/theme/classiceditor.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'plugins'. These properties are valid:
   object { postcssOptions?, execute?, sourceMap?, implementation? }
    at validate (/ProjectPath/my-ckeditor-build/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:191:11)
    at Object.loader (/ProjectPath/my-ckeditor-build/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:43:29)
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/theme/classiceditor.css 2:12-120 9:17-24 13:15-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditoruiview.js 9:0-36
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js 9:0-56 65:25-44
 @ ./ckeditor.js 3:0-85 7:43-60

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css (./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].use[1]!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'plugins'. These properties are valid:
   object { postcssOptions?, execute?, sourceMap?, implementation? }
    at validate (/ProjectPath/my-ckeditor-build/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:191:11)
    at Object.loader (/ProjectPath/my-ckeditor-build/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/index.js:43:29)
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css 2:12-118 9:17-24 13:15-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/placeholder.js 8:0-37
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/index.js 8:0-35 8:0-35
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/engine.js 8:0-43 8:0-43
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditorui.js 6:0-57 116:8-25
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js 8:0-48 68:22-37
 @ ./ckeditor.js 3:0-85 7:43-60
```

Searching in net I found https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/8315 branch and tried to salve from it with commands :

```
rm -f package-lock.json && rm -rf node_modules && npm install
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin@31.1.13: This package is no longer maintained. Please, read the migration path: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev/releases/tag/v32.0.0.

added 422 packages, and audited 423 packages in 31s

60 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

and next npm run build I gotthe same errors...

**Updated Block 5 :**

I applied your changes and
have got an warning message :

```
The `language` option is required by the `CKEditorWebpackPlugin` plugin.If you do not want to localize the CKEditor 5 code do not add this plugin to your webpack configuration.
```

a lot of errors :

```
> my-ckeditor-build@1.0.0 build
> webpack --mode production

assets by status 530 KiB [cached] 44 assets
orphan modules 3.4 MiB [orphan] 982 modules
runtime modules 1.8 KiB 6 modules
cacheable modules 3 MiB (javascript) 18.3 KiB (asset)
  asset modules 1.76 KiB (javascript) 18.3 KiB (asset)
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/ 1.39 KiB (javascript) 14.5 KiB (asset) 34 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/ 168 bytes (javascript) 1.03 KiB (asset) 4 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo/ 84 bytes (javascript) 660 bytes (asset) 2 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/ 84 bytes (javascript) 553 bytes (asset) 2 modules
    + 1 module
  javascript modules 2.99 MiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/ 46.5 KiB 22 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/ 15.6 KiB 3 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/ 475 bytes 2 modules
    + 5 modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/theme/clipboard.css (./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/theme/clipboard.css) 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> .ck.ck-editor__editable .ck.ck-clipboard-drop-target-position{display:inline;pointer-events:none;position:relative}.ck.ck-editor__editable .ck.ck-clipboard-drop-target-position span{position:absolute;width:0}.ck.ck-editor__editable .ck-widget:-webkit-drag>.ck-widget__selection-handle,.ck.ck-editor__editable .ck-widget:-webkit-drag>.ck-widget__type-around{display:none}:root{--ck-clipboard-drop-target-dot-width:12px;--ck-clipboard-drop-target-dot-height:8px;--ck-clipboard-drop-target-color:var(--ck-color-focus-border)}.ck.ck-editor__editable .ck.ck-clipboard-drop-target-position span{background:var(--ck-clipboard-drop-target-color);border:1px solid var(--ck-clipboard-drop-target-color);bottom:calc(var(--ck-clipboard-drop-target-dot-height)*-.5);margin-left:-1px;top:calc(var(--ck-clipboard-drop-target-dot-height)*-.5)}.ck.ck-editor__editable .ck.ck-clipboard-drop-target-position span:after{border-color:var(--ck-clipboard-drop-target-color) transparent transparent transparent;border-style:solid;border-width:calc(var(--ck-clipboard-drop-target-dot-height)) calc(var(--ck-clipboard-drop-target-dot-width)*.5) 0 calc(var(--ck-clipboard-drop-target-dot-width)*.5);content:"";display:block;height:0;left:50%;position:absolute;top:calc(var(--ck-clipboard-drop-target-dot-height)*-.5);transform:translateX(-50%);width:0}.ck.ck-editor__editable .ck-widget.ck-clipboard-drop-target-range{outline:var(--ck-widget-outline-thickness) solid var(--ck-clipboard-drop-target-color)!important}.ck.ck-editor__editable .ck-widget:-webkit-drag{zoom:.6;outline:none!important}
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/theme/clipboard.css 2:12-116 9:17-24 13:15-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/src/dragdrop.js 16:0-32
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/src/index.js 10:0-49 10:0-49
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/clipboard.js 8:0-46 8:0-46
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js 9:0-52 35:16-25
 @ ./ckeditor.js 4:0-77 10:4-20

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/theme/classiceditor.css (./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/theme/classiceditor.css) 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> .ck.ck-editor{position:relative}.ck.ck-editor .ck-editor__top .ck-sticky-panel .ck-toolbar{z-index:var(--ck-z-modal)}.ck.ck-editor__top .ck-sticky-panel .ck-toolbar{border-radius:0}.ck-rounded-corners .ck.ck-editor__top .ck-sticky-panel .ck-toolbar,.ck.ck-editor__top .ck-sticky-panel .ck-toolbar.ck-rounded-corners{border-radius:var(--ck-border-radius);border-bottom-left-radius:0;border-bottom-right-radius:0}.ck.ck-editor__top .ck-sticky-panel .ck-toolbar{border-bottom-width:0}.ck.ck-editor__top .ck-sticky-panel .ck-sticky-panel__content_sticky .ck-toolbar{border-bottom-width:1px;border-radius:0}.ck-rounded-corners .ck.ck-editor__top .ck-sticky-panel .ck-sticky-panel__content_sticky .ck-toolbar,.ck.ck-editor__top .ck-sticky-panel .ck-sticky-panel__content_sticky .ck-toolbar.ck-rounded-corners{border-radius:var(--ck-border-radius);border-radius:0}.ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable{background:var(--ck-color-base-background);border-radius:0}.ck-rounded-corners .ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable,.ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable.ck-rounded-corners{border-radius:var(--ck-border-radius);border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0}.ck.ck-editor__main>.ck-editor__editable:not(.ck-focused){border-color:var(--ck-color-base-border)}
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/theme/classiceditor.css 2:12-120 9:17-24 13:15-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditoruiview.js 9:0-36
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js 9:0-56 64:25-44
 @ ./ckeditor.js 3:0-85 7:43-60

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css (./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css) 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> .ck .ck-placeholder,.ck.ck-placeholder{position:relative}.ck .ck-placeholder:before,.ck.ck-placeholder:before{content:attr(data-placeholder);left:0;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;right:0}.ck.ck-read-only .ck-placeholder:before{display:none}.ck.ck-reset_all .ck-placeholder{position:relative}.ck .ck-placeholder:before,.ck.ck-placeholder:before{color:var(--ck-color-engine-placeholder-text);cursor:text}
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css 2:12-118 9:17-24 13:15-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/placeholder.js 8:0-37
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/index.js 8:0-35 8:0-35
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/engine.js 8:0-43 8:0-43
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditorui.js 10:0-57 111:12-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js 8:0-48 67:22-37
 @ ./ckeditor.js 3:0-85 7:43-60

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/renderer.css (./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/renderer.css) 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> .ck.ck-editor__editable span[data-ck-unsafe-element]{display:none}
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/renderer.css 2:12-115 9:17-24 13:15-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/renderer.js 12:0-34
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/index.js 36:0-54 36:0-54
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/engine.js 8:0-43 8:0-43
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditorui.js 10:0-57 111:12-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js 8:0-48 67:22-37
 @ ./ckeditor.js 3:0-85 7:43-60
...
```

**Updated Block 6:**
I rebuilded the project with success and having in package.json next definitions :

```
{
  "name": "my-ckeditor-build",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack --mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^35.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^35.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark": "^35.0.1",
    "@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video": "^35.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^38.3.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin": "^31.1.13",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

I overwrited ckeditor.js in my project with newly generated file and added plugin definition in app.js:

```
import Video from "@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video"
...
        const ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#content_editor'), {
                plugins: [Video],
                video: {},
                extraPlugins: [ NewUploadAdapterPlugin ]
            })

            .then(editor => {
   ...
```

But I got error in browsers console:

```
WARNING in ./resources/js/app.js 271:16-21
export 'default' (imported as 'Video') was not found in '@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video' (possible exports: AutoVideo)

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

If I replace Video var with AutoVideo (as is mentioned in warning message) I got the same error anyway...

**Updated Block 7:**

I checked all steps one more time and from package.json
removed definition of

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^38.0.1",
```

and run npm install one more time to exclude prior version

I added into file  app.blade.php link to newly generated and copied file

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/ckeditor.js') }}"></script>
```

But in which way have I to get ClassicEditorShortly var ?

This way

```
const ClassicEditorShortly = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');
```

does not work anymore. I tried the way below :

```
   const ClassicEditor = require('/js/ckeditor.js');
```

But got error :

```
ncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasAttribute')
at getjQuery...






$ node -v
v16.20.0
$ npm -v
8.19.4
```

Comment: Please read UPDATED BLOCK

Comment: Please read UPDATED BLOCK  #2

Answer (score 1):

Builds like [`@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic) (or [other predefined builds](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/predefined-builds.html)) already include their own set of pre-defined plugins and the base [CKEditor library](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/architecture/core-editor-architecture.html) bundled in.

If you add your own plugins, you therefore risk a `ckeditor-duplicated-modules` error (two different versions of a module or package included in your build), even when following [the requirements](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/plugins/installing-plugins.html#requirements) that you mention.

---

One possible workaround, for testing, would be to clone an existing build (like [`github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5`](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5)).
Rather than trying to import the plugin into an existing build (which can be problematic), create a custom build. That is more involved, but it gives you full control over the plugins and avoids duplicated modules.

- Clone the official build from GitHub.
- Install your required plugins.
- Modify the build configuration to include the desired plugins.
- Rebuild the editor.
- Use this custom build in your project.

Remember that when dealing with `npm` packages, it is not just about matching versions in `package.json`, but ensuring that the actual resolved versions in `package-lock.json` (or `yarn.lock` if you are using Yarn) are consistent and without duplicates. Always commit your lock file to your version control to ensure consistency across installations.

---

To clarify: The `ckeditor-duplicated-modules` error is often encountered when using third-party plugins that were built with a different version of CKEditor or when they have dependencies that conflict with the main build.

The two issues I can see are:

- **Version Compatibility**: CKEditor 5's architecture is modular, but plugins built for a certain version might not be compatible with other versions of the editor due to changes in the API or core.
- **Build Conflicts**: Using `ckeditor5-build-classic` and then adding another plugin on top can cause conflicts if that plugin contains some modules that are already part of the build.

The solution proposed above is to do a custom build, in order to use it instead of the `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic`. Simply link to the `dist/ckeditor.js` from your custom build and initialize it as you would with any other CKEditor build.

#### Step-by-step guide for creating a custom CKEditor 5 build:

1. **Setup**:

   Create a new directory for your custom CKEditor build:

   ```
   mkdir my-ckeditor-build
   cd my-ckeditor-build
   ```

   Initialize a new Node.js project:

   ```
   npm init -y
   ```
2. **Install Dependencies**:

   Install the base classic editor, the video plugin, and other necessary plugins:

   ```bash
   npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic @ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials @zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video
   ```
3. **Create a Custom Build**:

   Create a new file named `ckeditor.js` in the root of your project directory.

   ```js
   // ckeditor.js

   import ClassicEditorBase from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
   import EssentialsPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
   import Video from '@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video/src/video';

   export default class ClassicEditor extends ClassicEditorBase {}

   ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
       EssentialsPlugin,
       Video
   ];

   ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
       toolbar: {
           items: [
               'bold', 'italic', 'video'
               // ... other toolbar items
           ]
       },
       video: {
           upload: {
               types: ['mp4'],
               allowMultipleFiles: false
           }
       },
       // ... other configurations
   };
   ```
4. **Build the Editor**:

   Use the CKEditor webpack configurations to build your custom editor. Add the necessary scripts in `package.json`:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
       "build": "webpack --mode production",
       "start": "webpack --mode development"
   },
   ```

   You will need the CKEditor's webpack loader. Install it:

   ```bash
   npm install --save-dev @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin @ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils
   ```

   Create a webpack configuration `webpack.config.js`:

   ```js
   const path = require('path');
   const { styles } = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils');

   module.exports = {
       entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'ckeditor.js'),

       output: {
           path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
           filename: 'ckeditor.js',
           libraryTarget: 'umd',
           libraryExport: 'default'
       },

       module: {
           rules: [
               {
                   test: /\.svg$/,
                   use: ['raw-loader']
               },
               {
                   test: /\.css$/,
                   use: [
                       {
                           loader: 'style-loader',
                           options: {
                               injectType: 'singletonStyleTag',
                               attributes: {
                                   'data-cke': true
                               }
                           }
                       },
                       {
                           loader: 'postcss-loader',
                           options: styles.getPostCssConfig({
                               themeImporter: {
                                   themePath: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark')
                               },
                               minify: true
                           })
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
   };
   ```
5. **Build Your Custom Editor**:

   Now run the build script:

   ```bash
   npm run build
   ```

   That will create a `dist/ckeditor.js` file which you can include in your project.

That approach gives you complete control over what plugins are included, avoiding the duplicated modules error.

---

### Block 3

`ValidationError: Invalid options object. PostCSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.`

It is as if the `postcss-loader` configuration has undergone some changes in newer versions, specifically related to how the options are structured (hence the error message indicating that the `plugins` option is not valid anymore).

In your `webpack.config.js`, the part that deals with CSS (under the `module/rules` section) should be updated to match the newer `postcss-loader` API.

```js
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'style-loader',
            options: {
                injectType: 'singletonStyleTag',
                attributes: {
                    'data-cke': true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                postcssOptions: styles.getPostCssConfig({
                    themeImporter: {
                        themePath: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark')
                    },
                    minify: true
                })
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The main change is moving the previous `styles.getPostCssConfig()` call inside a `postcssOptions` field in the `postcss-loader` configuration.

If possible, ensure all CKEditor-related packages are of the same version to ensure compatibility.

After making these changes, clear the `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` again:

```bash
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
npm run build
```

---

The OP add **Updated Block 4 :**

> My package.json has next package versions :

```
{
  "name": "my-ckeditor-build",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack --mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^35.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^35.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark": "^35.0.1",
    "@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video": "^35.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^38.3.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin": "^31.1.13",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

> But running build I got a lot of errors, like

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
:

> my-ckeditor-build@1.0.0 build
> webpack --mode production

assets by status 539 KiB [cached] 1 asset
orphan modules 3.4 MiB [orphan] 982 modules
runtime modules 919 bytes 5 modules
cacheable modules 3.01 MiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ 83.7 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/ 14.5 KiB 34 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/ 47.6 KiB 26 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/ 16.2 KiB 5 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-undo/ 660 bytes 2 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/ 475 bytes 2 modules
    + 3 modules
  ./ckeditor.js + 506 modules 2.92 MiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js 6.67 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video/theme/video.css 241 bytes [built] [code generated] [1 error]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/align-bottom.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m9.239 13.938-2.88-1.663a.75.75 0 0 1 .75-1.3L9 12.067V4.75a.75.75 0 1 1 1.5 0v7.318l1.89-1.093a.75.75 0 0 1 .75 1.3l-2.879 1.663a.752.752 0 0 1-.511.187.752.752 0 0 1-.511-.187zM4.25 17a.75.75 0 1 1 0-1.5h10.5a.75.75 0 0 1 0 1.5H4.25z"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/index.js 27:0-60 67:4-15
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/core.js 8:0-41 8:0-41
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js 8:0-44 30:40-46
 @ ./ckeditor.js 4:0-77 10:4-20

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/align-center.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M2 3.75c0 .414.336.75.75.75h14.5a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75zm0 8c0 .414.336.75.75.75h14.5a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75zm2.286 4c0 .414.336.75.75.75h9.928a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H5.036a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75zm0-8c0 .414.336.75.75.75h9.928a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H5.036a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75z"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/index.js 31:0-60 71:4-15
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/core.js 8:0-41 8:0-41
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js 8:0-44 30:40-46
 @ ./ckeditor.js 4:0-77 10:4-20

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/align-justify.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M2 3.75c0 .414.336.75.75.75h14.5a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75zm0 8c0 .414.336.75.75.75h14.5a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75zm0 4c0 .414.336.75.75.75h9.929a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75zm0-8c0 .414.336.75.75.75h14.5a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75z"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/index.js 33:0-62 73:4-16
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/core.js 8:0-41 8:0-41
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js 8:0-44 30:40-46
 @ ./ckeditor.js 4:0-77 10:4-20

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/align-left.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M2 3.75c0 .414.336.75.75.75h14.5a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75zm0 8c0 .414.336.75.75.75h14.5a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75zm0 4c0 .414.336.75.75.75h9.929a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75zm0-8c0 .414.336.75.75.75h9.929a.75.75 0 1 0 0-1.5H2.75a.75.75 0 0 0-.75.75z"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/index.js 30:0-56 70:4-13
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/core.js 8:0-41 8:0-41
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js 8:0-44 30:40-46
 @ ./ckeditor.js 4:0-77 10:4-20


ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/align-middle.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M9.75 11.875a.752.752 0 0 1 .508.184l2.883 1.666a.75.75 0 0 1-.659 1.344l-.091-.044-1.892-1.093.001 4.318a.75.75 0 1 1-1.5 0v-4.317l-1.89 1.092a.75.75 0 0 1-.75-1.3l2.879-1.663a.752.752 0 0 1 .51-.187zM15.25 9a.75.75 0 1 1 0 1.5H4.75a.75.75 0 1 1 0-1.5h10.5zM9.75.375a.75.75 0 0 1 .75.75v4.318l1.89-1.093.092-.045a.75.75 0 0 1 .659 1.344l-2.883 1.667a.752.752 0 0 1-.508.184.752.752 0 0 1-.511-.187L6.359 5.65a.75.75 0 0 1 .75-1.299L9 5.442V1.125a.75.75 0 0 1 .75-.75z"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/index.js 28:0-60 68:4-15
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/core.js 8:0-41 8:0-41
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js 8:0-44 30:40-46
 @ ./ckeditor.js 4:0-77 10:4-20

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/align-right.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M18 3.75a.75.75 0 0 1-.75.75H2.75a.75.75 0 1 1 0-1.5h14.5a.75.75 0 0 1 .75.75zm0 8a.75.75 0 0 1-.75.75H2.75a.75.75 0 1 1 0-1.5h14.5a.75.75 0 0 1 .75.75zm0 4a.75.75 0 0 1-.75.75H7.321a.75.75 0 1 1 0-1.5h9.929a.75.75 0 0 1 .75.75zm0-8a.75.75 0 0 1-.75.75H7.321a.75.75 0 1 1 0-1.5h9.929a.75.75 0 0 1 .75.75z"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/index.js 32:0-58 72:4-14
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/core.js 8:0-41 8:0-41
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js 8:0-44 30:40-46
 @ ./ckeditor.js 4:0-77 10:4-20

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/align-top.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m10.261 7.062 2.88 1.663a.75.75 0 0 1-.75 1.3L10.5 8.933v7.317a.75.75 0 1 1-1.5 0V8.932l-1.89 1.093a.75.75 0 0 1-.75-1.3l2.879-1.663a.752.752 0 0 1 .511-.187.752.752 0 0 1 .511.187zM15.25 4a.75.75 0 1 1 0 1.5H4.75a.75.75 0 0 1 0-1.5h10.5z"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/index.js 29:0-54 69:4-12
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/core.js 8:0-41 8:0-41
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js 8:0-44 30:40-46
 @ ./ckeditor.js 4:0-77 10:4-20

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/bold.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M10.187 17H5.773c-.637 0-1.092-.138-1.364-.415-.273-.277-.409-.718-.409-1.323V4.738c0-.617.14-1.062.419-1.332.279-.27.73-.406 1.354-.406h4.68c.69 0 1.288.041 1.793.124.506.083.96.242 1.36.478.341.197.644.447.906.75a3.262 3.262 0 0 1 .808 2.162c0 1.401-.722 2.426-2.167 3.075C15.05 10.175 16 11.315 16 13.01a3.756 3.756 0 0 1-2.296 3.504 6.1 6.1 0 0 1-1.517.377c-.571.073-1.238.11-2 .11zm-.217-6.217H7v4.087h3.069c1.977 0 2.965-.69 2.965-2.072 0-.707-.256-1.22-.768-1.537-.512-.319-1.277-.478-2.296-.478zM7 5.13v3.619h2.606c.729 0 1.292-.067 1.69-.2a1.6 1.6 0 0 0 .91-.765c.165-.267.247-.566.247-.897 0-.707-.26-1.176-.778-1.409-.519-.232-1.31-.348-2.375-.348H7z"/></svg>
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/index.js 49:0-45 55:4-8
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/core.js 8:0-41 8:0-41
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js 8:0-44 30:40-46
 @ ./ckeditor.js 4:0-77 10:4-20

...

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css (./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css) 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> .ck .ck-placeholder,.ck.ck-placeholder{position:relative}.ck .ck-placeholder:before,.ck.ck-placeholder:before{content:attr(data-placeholder);left:0;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;right:0}.ck.ck-read-only .ck-placeholder:before{display:none}.ck.ck-reset_all .ck-placeholder{position:relative}.ck .ck-placeholder:before,.ck.ck-placeholder:before{color:var(--ck-color-engine-placeholder-text);cursor:text}
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css 2:12-118 9:17-24 13:15-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/placeholder.js 8:0-37
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/index.js 8:0-35 8:0-35
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/engine.js 8:0-43 8:0-43
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditorui.js 10:0-57 111:12-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js 8:0-48 67:22-37
 @ ./ckeditor.js 3:0-85 7:43-60

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/renderer.css (./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/renderer.css) 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> .ck.ck-editor__editable span[data-ck-unsafe-element]{display:none}
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/renderer.css 2:12-115 9:17-24 13:15-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/renderer.js 12:0-34
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/index.js 36:0-54 36:0-54
 @ ./node_modules/ckeditor5/src/engine.js 8:0-43 8:0-43
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditorui.js 10:0-57 111:12-29
 @ ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js 8:0-48 67:22-37
 @ ./ckeditor.js 3:0-85 7:43-60

ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/theme/components/button/button.css (./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/theme/components/button/button.css) 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
...

webpack 5.88.2 compiled with 73 errors in 16916 ms
```

> What is wrong in my installation ?

### Block 4

That should mean Webpack does not know how to handle `.svg` files that CKEditor is importing. You will need to set up the appropriate loaders in your Webpack configuration so it knows how to handle SVG (and potentially other file types).

That should requite [`file-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader) or [`raw-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) to handle `.svg` files.
But those are deprecated in favor of [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) with WebPack 5 (I would assume you are using [webpack 5](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/)).

Try and update your Webpack configuration to handle SVGs using the `asset/resource` type. That type emits a separate file and exports the URL, similar to what `file-loader` used to do:

```js
module.exports = {
  // other webpack configuration ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // other rules ...
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        type: 'asset/resource', // Use the asset/resource type for SVGs
        generator: {
          // If you want to specify the naming pattern for the output files
          filename: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Make sure that CKEditor's Webpack is aware of this and uses the public path correctly.

```js
const CKEWebpackPlugin = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin');
const CKERegex = /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/;

module.exports = {
  // other webpack configuration
  plugins: [
    // other plugins
    new CKEWebpackPlugin({
      // Use an absolute path to put the CKEditor's assets into the root of the static/media folder.
      outputDirectory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'static', 'media'),
      svgRegex: CKERegex,
      // Ensure the publicPath in webpack's output is correctly set.
      publicPath: '/static/media/',
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // other rules
      {
        test: CKERegex,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'raw-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      // The asset/resource rule for SVGs mentioned above.
    ]
  }
}
```

With these changes, your configuration should utilize Webpack 5's new asset modules to handle SVGs and properly configure CKEditor to work with them.

---

### Block 5:

That time, it seems related to CSS parsing in Webpack: the CSS loaders are not set up correctly to handle the CKEditor's CSS imports.

Regarding the warning, the CKEditorWebpackPlugin requires a `language` option to determine which language(s) to compile. If you are only interested in English, for instance, you would set it like:

```js
new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({
    language: 'en'
    // ... other options ...
})
```

Regarding the CSS parsing errrors, you can try and set up the CSS loaders:

```bash
npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader postcss-loader
```

Update your Webpack configuration to handle CSS, using [webpack `loaders/css-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/):

```js
module.exports = {
    // ... other webpack configuration ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            // ... other rules ...
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1
                        }
                    },
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            },
            // ... SVG handling, etc. ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Do make sure that the custom SVG handling rule (using the `asset/source`) for CKEditor does not overlap with other general SVG or CSS rules.

---

### Block 6

### Block 6

That block seems to show some discrepancies in how the CKEditor plugin is being imported and used in your project. The warning suggests that the default export you are trying to import from `@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video` does not exist and you should probably be using `AutoVideo` instead.

Also, go to `node_modules/@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video` and inspect its main file (usually mentioned in the `package.json`'s `main` field). See if there is a default export or only named exports. If you see something like:

```js
export default something;
```

Then you should be able to use the default import. But if you see:

```js
export { AutoVideo, ... };
```

Then, a named import is what you should be using. Try importing `AutoVideo` as a named import:

```js
import { AutoVideo } from "@zhufusheng/ckeditor5-video";
```

And then, use it like:

```js
plugins: [AutoVideo],
```

---

### Block 7:

Since you are including the CKEditor script directly in your HTML, you do not need to `require` or `import` it again in your JavaScript file. Once you have added the script in your HTML, `ClassicEditor` (or whatever you named it in your custom build) should be available globally in your JS.

So, instead of this:

```js
const ClassicEditor = require('/js/ckeditor.js');
```

You can directly use `ClassicEditor`. Just make sure you call it after the script has been loaded. A simple way to ensure this is to place your script at the bottom of your HTML or use a [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Note: The "`Cannot read properties of null`" error often comes up when trying to access a DOM element that does not exist or has not been rendered yet. Make sure the element you are trying to turn into a CKEditor instance (`#content_editor` from your previous snippet) is actually available in the DOM. That error might not be directly related to CKEditor but can occur if you try to initialize the editor on a non-existent element.

For instance, the element with the ID `content_editor` must be present in the HTML before the script tries to initialize CKEditor on it.

```html
<textarea id="content_editor"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, but your points seems too vague and complicated...

Comment: @mstdmstd Sure, I have edited the answer to clarify those points. But the proposed solution remains "complex", and I hope that with your bounty, you will find a simpler option.

Comment: Please read Updated Block 3

Comment: @mstdmstd I have edited the answer to address your comment/Block 3.

Comment: Please read Updated Block 4

Comment: @mstdmstd OK, I have addressed block 4 (but please keep those blocks in your question, that you can edit, rather than in the answer)

Comment: Please read Updated Block 5

Comment: @mstdmstd Sure, I have edited the answer to address block 5.

Comment: Please read Updated Block 6

Comment: Please read Updated Block 7

Comment: @mstdmstd I have edited the answer to address block 6, then block 7.

Comment: I still got error : app.js?id=c4e7401412024444b8267473e4d830e9:277 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasAttribute')
at getjQuery.
Please confirm if in file app.blade.php I added   line with <script src="/js/ckeditor.js"></script>
before
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>


I had to remove package  "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^35.0.0", from package.json and rebuild the project with nmp ?

\

Comment: @mstdmstd I have addressed your latest comment in [a separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76911799/6309): this one is now too long for Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

> I still got error :
>
> `app.js?id=c4e7401412024444b8267473e4d830e9:277 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasAttribute') at getjQuery`

If you see `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasAttribute') at getjQuery`, that should mean  there is an attempt to use a DOM element that is not available yet.

I confirm you need to make sure the scripts are loaded in the correct order in your blade file. If you are using the custom-built CKEditor, then you should indeed load the CKEditor script before your application's main JS file (`app.js`).

```html
<script src="/js/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

By doing this, the CKEditor script will have registered the global `ClassicEditor` object by the time `app.js` runs.

Before you try to initialize the CKEditor instance, double-check the DOM element you are binding it to (`#content_editor` in your earlier example) does exist. That means your initialization script should come after the target textarea or div in your HTML:

```html
<textarea id="content_editor"></textarea>
```

If you are dynamically generating or loading this element, you will need to make sure your editor initialization only happens after the element is in the DOM.

Or: another way to ensure that the DOM is ready before you try to initialize the CKEditor is by wrapping your initialization code inside a `DOMContentLoaded` event, as previously mentioned in block 7.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // CKEditor initialization code here
});
```

That would make the DOM is fully loaded before the code inside runs.

You mentioned that you have removed `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic` from `package.json` and rebuilt your project: See that you have cleared any caching mechanisms you may be using (browser cache, Laravel cache, service workers, etc.) so you are not loading an old version of your assets.

The error you have mentioned also seems to be related to jQuery. CKEditor 5 does not depend on jQuery. That makes me think there might be another script or function in your codebase (or in a third-party library you are using) that is causing this error. Try to pinpoint where this error is coming from and address it.
Try and create a minimal reproduction of the problem. Strip away everything that is not essential and try to reproduce the issue in a clean environment.